# Duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, duplicates

If I want to ask a question that has already been asked,but I can't understand its solution.Should I comment there for more explanation or ask mine by adding duplicate by myself.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139282/270345

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just my opinion, and definitely not an absolute one.

It depends on the age of the original question and how extensive the needed additional explanation is, but i'd say *if* the question is not "fresh" and you need a considerable amount of additional information, I'd ask a new question, referring to the older one, and clearly describe why you don't understand the answer on the existing question.

Asking additional explanation in a comment on an old question might be unnoticed and unlikely to have any effect on the answer. In a way it's a new question then about the answer of another one :)

Comment: That last part has more to do with the activity of the user than the question. If, say, a 5 year old post by Rinzwind or Oli gets a comment for clarification, I'd reasonably expect both to respond.

Comment: @muru True of course, although it might be tempting "not to notice" if you can hardly remember the post and the answer you gave. I guess this is one of the situations you can hardly create a solid rule for, and have to decide per case, based on common sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have enough reputation to comment. Comment.